# When push with FadeTransition and Hero animation, the icon will not disappear when page too fast to push again

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

When push with FadeTransition and Hero animation, the icon will frozen in the screen when the page too fast to push again. Anyone has idea to solve this bug?

This is the full code example to reproduce. I am push a Hero widget to another screen, it is work to push to another screen but it is still freeze in the screen if push again before the hero widget fade out.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class AppRoutes {
  static MaterialPageRoute? getRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case "/":
        return MainRoute(
          MyHomePage(),
          settings: settings,
        );
    }
  }
}

class MainRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  MainRoute(
    Widget widget, {
    RouteSettings? settings,
  }) : super(builder: (_) => widget, settings: settings);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) => AppRoutes.getRoute(
        settings,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => TestScreen(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.route),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({
    super.key,
    this.isSuccess = false,
  });

  final bool isSuccess;

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _redirectToDetailPage();
  }

  void _redirectToDetailPage() async {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
          maintainState: false,
          opaque: true,
          pageBuilder: (_, Animation<double> start, Animation<double> end) {
            return TestUnsuccess(
              test: end,
            );
          },
          transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
            return FadeTransition(
              opacity: animation,
              child: child,
            );
          },
          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Hero(
                  tag: 'payment_icon',
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.abc,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 32.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestUnsuccess extends StatefulWidget {
  final Animation<double> test;

  TestUnsuccess({
    required this.test,
  });

  @override
  TestUnsuccessState createState() => TestUnsuccessState();
}

class TestUnsuccessState extends State<TestUnsuccess> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Hero(
                tag: 'payment_icon',
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.abc,
                  size: 40,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16.0,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.home_filled,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    "/",
                    ModalRoute.withName('/'),
                  );

                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => TestAnother(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestAnother extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TestAnother> createState() => _TestAnotherState();
}

class _TestAnotherState extends State<TestAnother> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Use PageRouteBuilder with opaque: true: Set the opaque property of
> PageRouteBuilder to true. This ensures that the destination page
> covers the entire screen during the transition, preventing any frozen
> elements from being visible.

```
 Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    maintainState: false,
    opaque: true, // Ensure that the destination page covers the entire screen
    pageBuilder: (_, Animation<double> start, Animation<double> end) {
      return TestUnsuccess(
        test: end,
      );
    },
    transitionsBuilder:
        (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      return FadeTransition(
        opacity: animation,
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'unique_tag', // Ensure each Hero has a unique tag
          child: child,
        ),
      );
    },
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
  ),
);
```

Ensure that the `Hero` widgets in both the source and destination pages have the same unique tag. This should help prevent the icon from freezing on the screen during fast navigation.

Comment: i try to add maintainState: false,
    opaque: true,  but it is still not working. I have update my example which didn't wrap the Hero into the FadeTransition, any different between 2 way?

Comment: Yes, there is a big difference between these two

If you wrap the Hero widget in a FadeTransition, the Hero widget will fade in or out when it appears or disappears. This can create a smoother transition effect when the widget changes between screens.

If you don't wrap the Hero widget in a FadeTransition, the Hero widget will not fade in or out. It will simply appear or disappear instantaneously when transitioning between screens.

Comment: If i wrap the Hero widget in a FadeTransition, how can i place the target location in the Next screen? It means there are 3 Hero widget with same tag id in the same time? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class AppRoutes {
  static MaterialPageRoute? getRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case "/":
        return MainRoute(
          MyHomePage(),
          settings: settings,
        );
    }
  }
}

class MainRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  MainRoute(
    Widget widget, {
    RouteSettings? settings,
  }) : super(builder: (_) => widget, settings: settings);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) => AppRoutes.getRoute(
        settings,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => TestScreen(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.route),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({
    this.isSuccess = false,
  });

  final bool isSuccess;

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _redirectToDetailPage();
  }

  void _redirectToDetailPage() async {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
          maintainState: false,
          opaque: true,
          pageBuilder: (_, Animation<double> start, Animation<double> end) {
            return TestUnsuccess(
              test: end,
            );
          },
          transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
            return FadeTransition(
              opacity: animation,
              child: child,
            );
          },
          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return false;
        },
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Hero(
                  tag: 'payment_icon',
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.ac_unit,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 32.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestUnsuccess extends StatefulWidget {
  final Animation<double> test;

  TestUnsuccess({
    required this.test,
  });

  @override
  TestUnsuccessState createState() => TestUnsuccessState();
}

class TestUnsuccessState extends State<TestUnsuccess> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return false;
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Hero(
                tag: 'payment_icon',
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.ac_unit,
                  size: 40,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16.0,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    "/",
                    ModalRoute.withName('/'),
                  );

                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => TestAnother(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.home_filled,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestAnother extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TestAnother> createState() => _TestAnotherState();
}

class _TestAnotherState extends State<TestAnother> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this code looks same as my example?

Comment: I made changes in your code, that is why.